# python subprocess not working. it is not replacing variable output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have below function which is used check ping status

```
def pingOk(sHost):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system().lower()=="windows" else 'c', sHost), shell=True)
    except Exception, e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False

    return True
```

I tried to run the script

```
 pingOk(sHost)
```

I am getting below error:

```
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV64] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
Usage: ping -6 [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
             [-l preload] [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option]
             [-N nodeinfo_option] [-p pattern] [-Q tclass] [-s packetsize]
             [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option] [-w deadline]
             [-W timeout] destination
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "set_enviroment.py", line 54, in pingOk
    output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system().lower()=="windows" else 'c', sHost), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command 'ping -c 1 ' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Looks like its not formatting output. Please someone help what i am doing mistake

Comment: may be due to wrong format of using ping command since its displaying ping usage help i sugget you to print the command before and validate it in terminal.

Comment: Its working fine and I tested it, it is formatting variable issue. If i use hard code values it works fine

Comment: print("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system().lower()=="windows" else 'c', sHost)) and check you are getting proper command

Comment: Looks like IP formatting is empty thanks Pavan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the complaint was about `ping -c 1` , not `ping -{} 1 {}`, it's clear that the `.format` *did* happen.

Since the complaint was about `ping -c 1`  (note the trailing space), it's clear that the *second* argument to `.format` was an empty string.

The complaint that the command failed is presumably because `ping` expected a destination (hence all of the stderr complaining about usage).